# How do I check for collision correctly?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a Tile based game and I'm making the walls right now and it's not properly working

I have tried the `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.walls)`, but that trapped the player inside.

Game:

```
def run(self):
    # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
    self.playing = True
    while self.playing:
        self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
        self.events()
        self.update()
        self.draw()
        self.player.move()
```

Player:

```
def collideWithWalls(self, dx=0, dy=0):

    if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.walls):
        return True

def move(self, dx=0, dy=0):
    if not self.collideWithWalls(dx, dy):
        self.x += dx * TileSize
        self.y += dy * TileSize
```

I just expected it to stop me from going in it, but it made me go in it but no getting out.

Comment: in some tutorials you can see method: change only X, check collision (and eventually move back), next change only Y and check collision again. There is also other element: when you collide then you use wall position (left, right, top or bottom) as player position - ie. `player.rect.left = wall.rect.right`.  This way player will only touch wall, not go inside. examples: http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38

Answer (score 3):

It is not sufficient to determine if the current position of the player collides with a wall. You've to check if the new position of the player is on a wall. If a collision is determined, then the movement has to be discarded:

```py
def move(self, dx=0, dy=0):

    # store current position
    x, y = self.rect.x, self.rect.y

    # move player
    self.rect.x += dx * TileSize
    self.rect.y += dy * TileSize

    # determine collision
    if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.walls):

        # discard movement
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = x, y
```

Comment: That just doesn't let him move, no matter what. It looks like it works, but it doesn't. Almost. (I don't see what's going wrong.)

Comment: @jaden.joeyak In this case you've tp provide more code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In order to do that, I'd have to copy and paste all 4 files I'm using. Which is hundreds of lines.

Comment: @jaden.joeyak Note  `pg.sprite.spritecollideany` uses the `.rect` attribute, to perform the collision test. So ich changed `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` in the answer. But in the code of your question there is `self.x` and `self.y`, too. But you didn't provide any information how `self.x` and `self.y` is related to `self.rect`, so I wasn't able to consider this. Probably this is part of the problem.

Comment: there are built in variables in the rect.

Comment: @jaden.joeyak `self` is a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) rather than a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), isn't it. A sprite has no `.x` and `.y` properties.